# It is possible to deploy Filestore only when a kubernetes workflow is running?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working on a kubernetes workflow that needs to pass files of data (parquet dataframes mainly) between pods.

I found that the best option to share these files was an NFS server, and as I am working with google cloud environment I would like to use Filestore.

The trouble here is that I don't want to have a 24/7 Filestore storage running, I only want to deploy Filestore at the start of my workflow and delete the storage at the end of it.

Comment: How big are the files?  And are you passing data bi-directionally or is this a one way flow between the pods?

Comment: @GariSingh Files nowadays are between 300MB and 5GB. But I want a scalable system that should support bigger files in a future (for example, 40 GB file). Is a one way flow, but there is the possibility that one pods receive the input from multiple pods. The only solution I found was an NFS server.

Comment: How often do you want to use this Filestore (daily / weekly / monthly) ?
You can dynamically create Filestore, but I'm not sure that's the right/effective approach.

Comment: @matt_j I will use it daily and I will launch simultaneous workflows (so there will be simultaneous filestores). I am developing an etl project. This is the only solution I found to pass files of data between pods. The other solution is to mount an NFS server in the cluster with one persistent disk or other type of storage.

The workflow normally will take one hour or less, but it has to support a multiple hour process if it is needed.

Comment: What do you think about using [Longhorn](https://longhorn.io/) instead of an NFS server/Filestore ?
My short description of this tool can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1049968/604238).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Filestore CSI Driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-filestore-csi-driver) with storage class with a reclaim policy of delete.  This driver is not supported by Google Cloud support at this time.  Later this quarter, there should be a fully supported and managed version of the driver available as part of GKE.